# Write a Powershell function to take input from User and display it back

Tags: powershell, powershell-2.0, powershell-3.0, powershell-4.0

I have written below function in PowerShell and running it from Powershell ISE.
What I am expecting is to run provide argument inline and do some basic validation and print it back.

```
function Set-Version
{
    [CmdletBinding(SupportsShouldProcess=$true, ConfirmImpact='Medium')]
    [Alias()]
    [OutputType([int])]
    Param
    (
        # The path to the source directory. Default $Env:BUILD_SOURCESDIRECTORY is set by TFS.
        [Parameter(Mandatory=$false, Position=0)]
        [ValidateNotNullOrEmpty()]
        [string]$Path = "C:\",


        [Parameter(Mandatory=$false, Position=1)]
        [ValidateNotNullOrEmpty()]
        [string]$Number = "2.0.0.2",


        [Parameter(Mandatory=$false, Position=2)]
        [ValidateNotNullOrEmpty()]
        [string]$Format = "\d+\.\d+\.\d+\.\d+"
    )

    if (-not (Test-Path $Path)) {
        Write-Output "Path does not exist."
    }
}

    Write-Output $Path
    Write-Output $Number
    Write-Output $Version
    Set-Version -Path $Path -Number $Number -Version $Version
```

To run: I am using below syntax,

```
PS C:\> .\Set-Version.ps1
PS C:\> .\Set-Version -Path "C:\" -Number "10" -Version "2v"
```

However, nothing gets displayed on screen.

Am I missing something basic??

Comment: Where are the variables `$here` and `$sut` being defined?

Comment: Apologies - I have corrected that bit of code. However, problem with this code is it also shows up error with "Cannot find an appropriate constructor to instantiate the custom attribute object for type 'Alias'".

Comment: Remove the alias desciptor. It isn't doing anything anyway.

Comment: The "Alias" decorator requires that you supply a desired alias. It cannot be null. What are you actually trying to accomplish with it?

Comment: Also, you've used the tags for PowerShell 2, 3, and 4; the [Alias()] attribute only exists in 4 and later - what version of PowerShell are you _actually_ using (`$psversiontable`)?

Comment: Also, where are you defining `$Version`?

Comment: Finally figured it out, removing alias() from the code and have removed last line containing 'Set-Version' - it served no purpose.